# manage UIActivityIndicatorView from another class

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

in my app there are 2 view controllers both embed in navigation controller. I'm using swift 2 and Xcode 7.1.1
To manage all the code related to downloading operation in a most simple way I want to move this code in another new class. The problem is to manage the activity of UIActivityIndicatorView from this class. here you are the code in my view controller. now work perfectly.

```
class VC2: UITableViewController, DetailVC2Delegate {



    var privateDB: CKDatabase!

    let spinner:UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...

        configuraSpinner()
        self.spinner.startAnimating()
            fetchChild(parent)
    }

    func configuraSpinner(){
        spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .Gray
        spinner.center = self.view.center
        spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
        spinner.color = UIColor.redColor()
        self.parentViewController?.view.addSubview(spinner)
    }
```

and in this class I manage the activity in a block operation like this:

```
func fetchChild(parent: CKRecord){
//...
//...
queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in
            if (error != nil) {
            print(".... - \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("....")

                if self.spinner.isAnimating() {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.spinner.stopAnimating()
                    })
                }
//...
  privateDB.addOperation(queryOperation)
}
```

So, the question is move this code in another class and from this new class be able to start, stop and ask the state of the spinner.

any suggestion?

Comment: you can add delegates/blocks for handling event from other classes.

Answer (score 1):

set the delegate of new class equals to current class. or you can make the spinner global so you can reach from anywhere.